# IllegalStateException when passing function as param

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a custom adapter for a recyclerview

BaseRecyclerView.kt

```
abstract class BaseRecyclerView {
    abstract class Adapter<ITEM : Any, B : ViewDataBinding>(
        private val listener : ((s : Station) -> View.OnClickListener)?,
        @LayoutRes private val layoutResId: Int,
        private val bindingVariableId: Int? = null
    ): RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder<B>>()

    ...
```

it accepts a nullable function as a parameter,
so then I created an object for the recyclerview in the activity

StationActivity.kt

```
deprListView.adapter = object : BaseRecyclerView.Adapter<Station, StationListItemBinding>(
                listener = { s ->
                    View.OnClickListener {
                        Toast.makeText(this@StationActivity, "${s.stationName} : ${s.stationCode}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                },
                layoutResId = R.layout.station_list_item,
                bindingVariableId = BR.station
            ) {}
```

it doesn't show any errors in the editor, but on build it returns an error

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation`

theres no error when I set `listener = null,` (I check if listener is null then set the listener if not null)

so there must be something I'm misunderstanding about functions in kotlin...
what might be causing this error?

```
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation
File being compiled at position: file://C://app/src/main/java/com/example/expressbus1/ui/station/StationActivity.kt
The root cause java.lang.AssertionError was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner$doInline$lambdaInliner$1.visitMethodInsn(MethodInliner.kt:314)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationErrorHandler.lambda$static$0(CompilationErrorHandler.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generateModule(CodegenFactory.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.doGenerateFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:39)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:637)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:195)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:165)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:349)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:237)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:606)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: <init> call doesn't correspond to object transformation info for 'com/example/expressbus1/ui/station/StationActivity$onCreate$1$1.<init>': null
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner$doInline$lambdaInliner$1.visitMethodInsn(MethodInliner.kt:314)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodInsnNode.accept(MethodInsnNode.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnList.accept(InsnList.java:144)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:792)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:389)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.access$doInline(MethodInliner.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner$doInline$lambdaInliner$1.visitMethodInsn(MethodInliner.kt:301)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodInsnNode.accept(MethodInsnNode.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnList.accept(InsnList.java:144)
    at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:792)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:389)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:70)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.inlineCall(InlineCodegen.kt:261)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.performInline(InlineCodegen.kt:142)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.PsiInlineCodegen.genCallInner(PsiInlineCodegen.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallGenerator$DefaultImpls.genCall(CallGenerator.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.PsiInlineCodegen.genCall(PsiInlineCodegen.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2533)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2476)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:13)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValueWithLeaveTask.putSelector(StackValue.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.putStackValue(ExpressionCodegen.java:384)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.returnExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1701)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$FunctionDefault.doGenerateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:666)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:473)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:260)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:176)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.gen(FunctionCodegen.java:147)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genSimpleMember(MemberCodegen.java:197)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateDeclaration(ClassBodyCodegen.java:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateBody(ClassBodyCodegen.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:302)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateClassesAndObjectsInFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:68)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: Can you show more of the stack trace.

Comment: @Tenfour04 forgot the most important part oops